# computing power in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, statistical-power

How can I compute the power of Dixon discordancy test in R. As there are functions for many other tests like t.test, ANOVA, proportions test etc. but not for this one. Any help will be warmly appreciated.

Comment: A power study using Monte Carlo simulation is described in detail at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3967640/.  `R` could reproduce this work (on a small scale, because its `dixon.test` calculations are slow).

Comment: Thanx @whuber for your intention. I am following the same paper which you have mentioned but there is no detail on how the power of these four test statistics are computed. Now if I programmed it on R as there is no direct function for these tests, then for power can I use the following code??
power=pnorm(TN8,lower.tail=TRUE)  where                           TN8=max((x[n]-x[n-1])/(x[n]-x[1]),(x[2]-x[1])/(x[n]-x[1]))

Comment: looking forward for the answer...!